# How do I override a field in a base class with a property in a derived class?

Tags: python, properties, overriding

I have a base class that uses a field:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, member):
        self.member = member
```

And a derived class that would like to promote this to a property, and add some behaviour:

```
class Derived(Base):
    @property
    def member(self):
        return super(Derived, self).member

    @member.setter
    def member(self, value):
        print "intercepting setter"
        super(Derived, self).member = value
```

However, this doesn't correctly delegate to the base class:

```
>>> d = Derived(0)
intercepting setter

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    d = Derived(0)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 3, in __init__
    self.member = 2
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 9, in member
    super(Derived, self).member = value
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'member'
```

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access the super's `member` as if it were a class attribute. Try with:

```
class Derived(Base):
    @property
    def member(self):
        print "intercepting getter"
        return self._member

    @member.setter
    def member(self, value):
        print "intercepting setter"
        self._member = value
```

Comment: I just understood that your answer is what I ended up with in my answer.

Comment: _"as if it were a class attribute"_ - Wouldn't that appear as `super(Derived).member`?

Comment: No, that usage of `super` wouldn't give you access to an hypothetical `member` attribute of `Base` (you would need a bound super object for that, providing an instance like this: `super(Derived, self).member`). Anyway, in your code, `member` is an **instance attribute** initialized in the constructor, and `super` is for accessing stuff from base classes, not stuff from instances of classes.

Comment: I guess my mistake was assuming that there was a distinction between a "Base instance attribute" and a "Derived instance attribute"

Comment: where does the `self._member` field come from here?

Answer (score 2):

I think that *promoting* a member to a property is the correct way of doing it.  It is like having an `int` member in the base and changing it to a method in the derived class.  Or like having a normal method and changing it to a static or class method in the inheriter.  I guess this just breaks the concept.

You have several options to solve the issue.

I. How about introducing a property of a different (similar) name which then relays all access to the inherited original name?  This would be very simple, won't break anything inherited from the base class.  But it would also not allow intercepting access to the original member (done in the base class or whereever).

II. Replace the inherited member completely.  This just means store the value in a different member and create the property totally from scratch.  Later then let it access the store of the original:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, member):
        self.member = member

    def baseAccess(self):
        return self.member

class Derived(Base):
    @property
    def member(self):
        print "getter",
        return self.memberStore

    @member.setter
    def member(self, value):
        print "setter",
        self.memberStore = value

b = Base(24)
print "Base(24)"
print "b.member", b.member
print "b.baseAccess()", b.baseAccess()
d = Derived(23)
print "Derived(23)"
print "d.member", d.member
print "d.baseAccess()", d.baseAccess()

b.member = 43
print "b.member = 43"
print "b.member", b.member
print "b.baseAccess()", b.baseAccess()
d.member = 42
print "d.member = 42"
print "d.member", d.member
print "d.baseAccess()", d.baseAccess()
```

This is the output:

```
Base(24)
b.member 24
b.baseAccess() 24
setter getter Derived(23)
d.member getter 23
d.baseAccess() getter 23
b.member = 43
b.member 43
b.baseAccess() 43
setter d.member = 42
d.member getter 42
d.baseAccess() getter 42
```

So all the interceptors are properly taken into account.

Comment: Surely `self.memberStore = self.member` is a no op, since `self.member` returns `self.memberStore`?

Comment: You are right!  That line is not necessary.  I remove it.  And then the whole `__init__()` isn't necessary anymore.  Removing that, too.

Comment: Also, `.baseAccess()` seems to be doing derived access, since it fires the interceptor

Comment: In the instance of the derived class, yes.  Not in the instance of the base class.  I think this is what one would like to have, isn't it?

Comment: I guess my point is that there is no case where `self.member` isn't just proxied by `b.baseAccess()`